# What suport does Scala have for class/object level access control?

Tags: scala, scope, access-control

Java supports public and package-private access modifier on the class level ([Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)). What access modifier does Scala support for classes/objects access control?

The only documentation I can find mentions method level access control exclusively, any documentation that mentions class/object access control  would be very helpful.

Comment: you can freely write code like `private class Foo private(val bazz : Int)`. It would mean private to enclosing object class `Foo` with private constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same access modifiers for classes you use for methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good [blog post by Alvin Alexander](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package) that should help you answer those questions. More in-depth information on Classes & Objects is available in the [Scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#modifiers).

Comment: Unfortunately that post only discusses method level access control. It does not mention class/object level control.

Comment: @MikeRylander I've linked in the spec that speaks to Classes & Objects.